# How to download videos from any site using terminal based command?

Tags: 13.10

I want to download any videos form any site using terminal command , I know "`youtube-dl`" but it doesn't download videos from some sites like khan academy so, what is the best for that ?

Comment: +1 for calrifying what you need and stating what you know

Comment: The main issue is not to download the video file (wget can do) but it's to find the url to download the video file.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `youtube-dl` for that. Just copy the url of the video. In case you don't know about the link. Just right click & see **View Frame Info** you'll see the video url there. Then

```
youtube-dl videourl
```

Comment: No need to downvote this. The info in the question is deprecated e.g., [Kahn academy site is supported now](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `wget` for that.

type the following command on terminal:

```
 apt­-get install wget
```

Download a single file using wget.

```
 wget "your video url link"
```

Comment: This does not work for videos. Unless there is a special flag which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: wget should be fine, unless the url is not the video src but the page then it will grab the html page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use movgrab.

To install Movgrab:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install movgrab
```

Check [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/movgrab-command-line-video-downloader.html) for more information

Or you can download the source, extract it and compile it:

```
 wget https://sites.google.com/site/columscode/files/movgrab-1.2.1.tar.gz
 tar xvf movgrab-1.2.1.tar.gz
 cd movgrab-1.2.1/
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

Comment: when I type this command "sudo apt-get install movgrab" I have this error "E: Unable to locate package movgrab
"

Comment: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/precise/main/base/movgrab take it from here

Comment: have you add the repositoy?

Comment: Thanks I installed it successfully but when type command like this "movgrab http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3t-5UtvDN0
" to download it take me video but doesn't work . I try several videos and I have the same results

Comment: check the link above.. Its better to insert the link between double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
wget --force-yes "'echo$http:url'"
```

and it might work fine this way.